# How would I add a parameter to entity framework raw sql command

Tags: c#, entity-framework

How would I add a parameter to following Entity Framework raw SQL command? For example, what if I wanted to make the `Id` a parameter?

```
        using (var context = new NorthwindDBEntities())
        {
            context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(@"
                UPDATE dbo.Customers 
                SET Name = 'Test' WHERE Id = 1
            ");

        }
```

Comment: I know your question is about creating parameters (SqlParameter) if you whatever reason want to, but, in your case if you want to call a raw sql command like an UPDATE, why not use a string.Format("UPDATE ... WHERE Id = {0}", typedIdVariable) instead of a SqlParameter?

Comment: @natenho: because, no matter what, you shouldn't be tempted to assemble SQL via string concatenation. While it will probably work for integer substitutions (this user's specific case), it leaves you ripe for SQL injection in other cases. A bad habit best avoided.

Comment: Which brings me to another related question. You know how you can call context.usp_stored_proc(parm1,parm2)? Is that subject to an injection attack?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(@"UPDATE dbo.Customers 
            SET Name = 'Test' WHERE Id = @Id", new SqlParameter("Id", 1));
```

in case of multiple parameters

```
context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(@"UPDATE dbo.Customers 
            SET Name = 'Test' WHERE Id = @id and Name =@name", 
               new SqlParameter("Id", id),
               new SqlParameter("name", fname));
```

Comment: How can we implement it for multiple parameters?

Answer (score 6):

The following code should work for this scenario:

```
    using (var context = new NorthwindDBEntities())
    {
        context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(@"
            UPDATE dbo.Customers 
            SET Name = 'Test' WHERE Id = {0}
        ", 1);
    }
```

You can also use `SqlParameter` and use @id:

```
    using (var context = new NorthwindDBEntities())
    {
        context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(@"
            UPDATE dbo.Customers 
            SET Name = 'Test' WHERE Id = @id
        ", new SqlParameter("id", 1));
    }
```

Comment: How can we implement it for multiple parameters?